# If a change of basis preserves the Lie bracket, why is the automorphism group of a Lie algebra not the entire general linear group?

Tags: lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

According to [Knapp (chapter 1, section 14)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2453-0), an automorphism of a Lie algebra is an invertible linear map $L$ that preserves brackets: $[L(X),L(Y)]=L[X,Y]$. Since this just means that the brackets must be given by the change of basis formula, I’m puzzled that he then goes on to say that $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb R}\mathfrak g \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_\mathbb R (\mathfrak g)$. Why isn’t the set inclusion an equality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by “the brackets must be given by the change of basis formula”? If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra and you pick a basis $B=\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, then you can write $[x_i,x_j] = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{ij}^k x_k$, and the scalars $(c_{ij}^k)_{i,j,k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$ (called the “structure constants” with respect to the basis $B$) completely determine the Lie bracket.

If $L$ is an invertible linear map and $L(x_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n l_{ij}x_i$, we can write out the conditions on the matrix of $L$ given by the requirement that $[L(x),L(y)] = L([x,y])$ explicitly in terms of the structure constants:

$$[L(x_i),L(x_j)] = \left[\sum_{p=1}^n l_{pi}x_p,\sum_{q=1}^n l_{qj} x_q\right] = \sum_{p,q,r=1}^n l_{pi}l_{qj}c_{pq}^r x_r$$

On the other hand,

$$L([x_i,x_j]) = L\left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_{ij}^kx_k\right)= \sum_{k,r=1}^n l_{rk}c_{ij}^kx_r$$

Thus $L$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$ precisely when

$$\sum_{k=1}^n l_{rk}c_{ij}^k = \sum_{p,q=1}^n l_{pi}l_{qj}c_{pq}^r.$$

This is a system of $n^3$ degree 2 equations in the entries of the matrix $(l_{ij})$.

Hopefully this convinces you that you the condition that $L([x,y]) = [L(x),L(y)]$ for all $x,y \in \mathfrak{g}$ is not automatically satisfied by any element of $\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$, but to be completely concrete, take $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{s}_2$ the two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra. This has basis $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $[x_1,x_2]=x_2$ (and all other brackets of basis elements $0$ by the alternating property) so that the structure constants are zero except for $c_{12}^2$.  Then if $L\colon \mathfrak{s}_2 \to \mathfrak{s}_2$ is a linear map with matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$ we see that the entries of the matrix must satisfy

$$r=1: \quad l_{12} =0$$
$$r=2: \quad l_{22} = l_{11}l_{22}$$

Since $L \in \mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$, it follows that the matrix of $L$ has the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ l_{21} & l_{22} \end{array}\right)$ (where $l_{22} \neq 0$ since we require $L$ to be invertible).

Comment: I should have said what Deitrich rightly started his answer with! If the Lie algebra is abelian, then the automorphism group is the entire general linear group, so I took $\mathfrak{s}_2$ as the smallest case where you might find $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{s}_2)\neq \mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{s}_2)$.

Comment: I meant the change of basis formula I mentioned in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679129/does-the-action-of-rmgln-on-lie-brackets-preserve-the-jacobi-identity.

Answer (score 4):

For a real  abelian Lie algebra $L$ all bijective linear maps $L\colon L\rightarrow L$ satisfy
$$
[L(x),L(y)]=0=L([x,y]).
$$
Hence ${\rm Aut}(L)=GL_3(\Bbb R)$.
However, in general such maps do not preserve the Lie bracket. For an easy example consider $\mathfrak{n}_3(\Bbb R)$, the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra. Then we have
$$
{\rm Aut}(\mathfrak{n}_3(\Bbb R))=\left\{ \left. \begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 \cr c & d & 0 \cr e & f & ad-bc \end{pmatrix}\,\right| ad-bc\neq 0\right\},
$$
which is different form $GL_3(\Bbb R)$. So the inclusion usually is not an equality.

Comment: Could you show how you calculated $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak n_3(\mathbb R))$?

Comment: Hi Dietrich! I edited your answer to make the central bar taller. Obviously, feel free to revert it (or ask me to undo it) if you don't like the way it looks.

Comment: @BrianTung Excellent, thank you!

Comment: So write $L(e_i)=r_i\cdot e_1+s_i\cdot e_2+t_i\cdot e_3$ and equate, say, $L(e_3)=[L(e_1),L(e_2)]$. This gives conditions on $r_i,s_i,t_i$, because a basis representation can only be zero if all coefficients are zero. So $L$ already can no longer be an arbitrary matrix in $GL(3)$.

Comment: Do you mean $L(e_i) = r_i\cdot x + s_i\cdot y + t_i\cdot z$? What do you mean by a “basis representation”?

Comment: I calculated $\phi([x,y]) = [\phi (x),\phi(y)] = [ae_1 + ce_2 + ee_3, be_1 + de_2 + fe_3] = (ad-bc)e_3$. Therefore $[x,y] = (ab-cd)\phi^{-1}(z)$, but here I’m stuck.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & 0 \\ c & d & 0 \\ e & f & ad-bc\end{array}\right)\right\}$? $\mathbb Re_3$ is $D(\mathfrak n_3)$, so an automorphism will induce an automorphism on $\mathfrak{n}_3/D(\mathfrak{n}_3)$ which is just a linear map, but it seems like any lift of such a linear map is an automorphism provided that it sends $e_3$ to the determinant of that linear map. For example $\phi(e_1)=e_1+e_3$, $\phi(e_2)=e_2+e_3$ and $\phi(e_3)=e_3$ seems to work.

Comment: To put it another way, the map $\mathfrak{n}_3 \to \mathfrak{n}_3/D(\mathfrak{n_3}) \cong \mathfrak{gl}_1^{\oplus 2}$ splits, but not canonically (which would seem to have to be the case if the automorphism group was $\mathrm{GL}_2$).

Comment: @krm2233 Yes, you are right. There is an article showing it wrongly, but now I have computed it myself and of course you are right.

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, with basis representation I mean that we can express any vector (so for example $L(e_1)\in \Bbb R^3$) as a linear combination $re_1+se_2+te_3$ with the basis elements $e_1,e_2,e_3$. This is my basis, not $x,y,z$, which are arbitrary vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you will like a much shorter and easier version of the above answers.

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the non-abelian $2$-dimensional Lie algebra with underlying vector space $V=\Bbb R^2$ and basis $(x,y)$. We may assume
that $[x,y]=x$. Let $L$ be the invertible linear map in $GL(V)$ given by $L(x)=y$ and $L(y)=x$. Then, if $L$ preserves Lie brackets,  we have

$$L(x)=L([x,y])=[L(x),L(y)]=[y,x]=-[x,y]=-x,$$
which is not true. So $L$ doesn't preserve Lie brackets, and there is no equality between ${\rm Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ and $GL(V)\cong GL_2(\Bbb R)$. Indeed $L\in GL(V)$, but not in ${\rm Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ .

Thus you see that preserving Lie brackets is not a "change of basis" formula, but a strong condition on the linear map $L$.