# Does the action of $\rm{GL}(n)$ on Lie brackets preserve the Jacobi identity?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The space of all $n$-dimensional complex Lie algebras $\mathfrak g\simeq\mathbb C^n$ can be identified with “the Lie algebra variety” $\mathcal L_n$, which is the closed subset of $V_n := \mathfrak g^*\wedge \mathfrak g^*\otimes \mathfrak g$ cut out by $n^4$ quadratic equations in the structure constants $\mu^k_{ij} := \langle \mu(e_i,e_j), e_k\rangle$
\begin{equation}
    \mu^s_{ir}\mu^r_{jk}+\mu^s_{jr}\mu^r_{ki} + \mu^s_{kr}\mu^r_{ij} = 0 \tag{1}%{Jacobi in the structure constants}
\end{equation}
imposed by the Jacobi identity.
According to [Jorge Lauret. On the moment map for the variety of lie algebras](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123602001088), the isomorphism class of a Lie algebra $\mu\in \mathcal L_n$ is the orbit $\operatorname{GL}(n)\cdot\mu$ under the ‘change of basis’ action of $\operatorname{GL}(n)$ on $V_n$.

I am confused here because as far as I know, by definition, two Lie algebras $\mathfrak g_{\mu}$ and $\mathfrak g_{\mu’}$ are isomorphic only if there is an invertible linear transformation $h:\mathfrak g_\mu \rightarrow \mathfrak g_{\mu’}$ such that the brackets $\mu$ and $\mu’$ are related by

$$h(\mu(e_i,e_j)) = \mu’(h(e_i),h(e_j))\tag{2},$$

i.e. if $h \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g_\mu) \subset \operatorname{GL}(\mathfrak g_\mu)$.
Thus, the isomorphism class of $\mu\in\mathcal L_n$ should be given by the orbit $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g)\cdot \mu$ and not by $\operatorname{GL}(n)\cdot \mu$. Did Lauret mean a different notion of isomorphism of Lie algebras, such as only requiring the existence of the invertible linear transformation $h$ and not $(2)$?

Furthermore, I rewrote $(1)$ under the action $\mu\mapsto h\cdot \mu$, where $h\in \operatorname{GL}(n)$ and $h\cdot \mu(x,y) = h\mu(h^{-1}x,h^{-1}y)$, and obtained \begin{equation}
    (h\cdot\mu^s_{ir})(h\cdot\mu^r_{jk})+(h\cdot\mu^s_{jr})(h\cdot\mu^r_{ki}) + (h\cdot\mu^s_{kr})(h\cdot\mu^r_{ij}) = 0, \tag{3}
\end{equation}
where $h\cdot\mu^s_{ir}=\langle h\mu(h^{-1}e_i,h^{-1}e_j), e_k\rangle$. However, it’s not clear to me $(3)$ is satisfied if $(1)$ is, i.e. that $\mathcal L_n$ is indeed preserved by the action of $\operatorname{GL}(n)$.

Comment: This is written in quite a convoluted way but I think the answer is no. An invertible linear map on $\mathfrak{g}$ will not, in general, preserve the Lie bracket. You are looking for the subgroup $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ of Lie algebra automorphisms

Comment: Hi @Callum, thanks! Could you comment where my writing was convoluted? You’re right that only invertible linear maps from $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$ will preserve the Lie bracket of $\mathfrak g$, but I’m asking about invertible linear maps preserving the Lie algebra variety $\mathcal L$.

Comment: Ah I have realised I misread your question I thought you were asking about a specific Lie bracket rather than the set of all possible ones. Still though it is probably still easier to use brackets rather than structure constants. So that would read $h[[h^{-1}A, h^{-1}B],h^{-1}C] = h[h^{-1}A,[h^{-1}B,h^{-1}C]] - h[h^{-1}B,[h^{-1}A,h^{-1}C]]$ if $h$ preserved the Jacobi identity and this doesn't look likely to hold to me